# ¿Como agregar un valor a colspan dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<td class="total" colspan=""> Areas </td>
```

Como desde jquery le puedo ingresar un valor que tengo en una varibale global?

Comment: dentro de esa td la idea es que desde el javascript empieze a manipular es colspan dependiendo al dato que vaya trayendo la base de datos a medida del tiempo puede ser 5 o 6 o 7, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque no se si es el unico td que quieras agregarle eso, o son todos los de la tabla , si es solo a ese agrega un id a tu td para que sea mas fácil de obtener.

```
$(".total").attr("colspan", tuVariableGlobal);
```